# How do I get a substring of a LPCTSTR?

Tags: c++, string, winapi

How do I get a substring of a LPCTSTR?

Comment: From my understanding LPCTSTR is somewhat like const char *, and if that's the case then you'll need to make a copy and put a nul terminator at index both.find("-")...

Comment: @wildplasser its a string type defined by Windows.  The letters mean the following IIRC.  L - long, P - pointer, C - const, T - indicates either char or wchar depending on Unicode setting, STR - string.  So its a string pointer type with a lot of info packed into the name.

Comment: Depending on compile options, it could be `const char *` *or* `const wchar_t *`.

Comment: you shouldn't initialize a `LPCTSTR` with a plain string literal - you need to use the `_T()` (or `TEXT()`) macro as the `T` string and character types are potentially wide characters...

Comment: Which language are you using? C or C++? Please pick one. And what do you mean by `LPCTSTR`? What I know as `LPCTSTR` does not have methods.

Comment: Then I suggest to remove the C tag and add some windows-framework-hungarian-babylon-tag instead. (In C, "both" could be a pointer to struct with find() a structure member)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LPCSTR` is just fancy name for `char *`, it doesn't have methods.

If you use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) you could use the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) methods to extract the first and second part of the string.

**Edit:** As noted by Christoph, the type of `TCHAR` differs depending on if `UNICODE` is defined or not. If `UNICODE` is defined (check with `#ifdef UNICODE`, do a Google search on preprocessor to learn more about things like `#define` and `#ifdef`) you need to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

**Edit 2:** An easier solution than checking if you need to use `std::string` or `std::wstring` all the time, is to follow the advice of Konrad Rudolph and create a new typedef similar to `std::string` and `std::wstring`. Something like this:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

And then use that string type internally.

Comment: So I need to copy it to a std::string, get the substring, then copy it back to the char *?

Comment: @Holtorf Not necessarily. The superior solution is not to use `LPCTSTR` at all. Or, if you have to, you still don’t need to copy in most cases since you can simply use a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` internally and call its `c_str()` method whenever you need to pass it to a method requiring an `LPCTSTR`.

Comment: @Holtorf If you really need a char pointer, you can use the [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method.

Comment: I'll agree that not using LPCTSTR would be the best option, but until I get a chance to re-write the legacy code that I am using, is there a good workaround?

Comment: @Holtorf: [strstr or wcsstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz(v=vs.71).aspx).  But seriously, convert to `std::string` wherever you can.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It turns out the string manipulation I was doing worked, but was ruined by a pointer problem.  Go figure.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, as LPCTSTR is a TCHAR*, then you can "substring" quite easily using `_tcschr`...depending on what your use case is.

```
TCHAR* exepath = getTheFullPathToThisProcess();
TCHAR* extension = _tcschr(exepath,'.'); //extension is a valid c-string containing '.exe'
//where is the last "\"?
TCHAR* slash = _tcsrchr(exepath,'\\');
*slash = 0;//exepath is now shortened to the path pre the filename of this process.
```

Might be easier for you if you are comfortable in c-string land.

EDIT : Forgot that LPCTSTR is a const! You would need to do a `_stprintf(copy,"%s",exepath)` in that case... so may not be worth it. But will leave this here as an alternative anyway.

Comment: Should make sure slash is not NULL before trying to set the new value.. I also like to use '\0' for the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the fact that string is actually a template itself.

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR, std::char_traits<TCHAR>, std::allocator<TCHAR> > tstring;
```

Then use 
    tstring str( _T("Hello world" ) );

```
tstring sub = str.substr(6, 3 );
```

Unfortunately there is no tcout unless you #define it somewhere:

```
 #ifdef _UNICODE
 #define tcout wcout
 #else
 #define tcout cout
 #endif
```

Now I can print my string

```
 tcout << sub << static_cast<TCHAR>('\n');
```

Note that in general code like this gets very messy, and will often lead to enormous bloat.

Answer (score 3):

use _tcsstr() to find a substring in a LPCTSTR

an LPCSTR is either a pointer to an ANSI string ('char') or a unicode string ('wchar')
you don't need to do any conversion to stl:string etc.
just call the appropriate flavor of strstr() which is what _tcsstr() does

Answer (score 2):

This is to convert into std::string -

```
LPCTSTR astring ="A random string";
std::string temp = astring;
```

Then use basic_string::find  to get position of substrings separator ("-" was before  your editing) and basic_string::erase to erase string after this position. 
Consult with MSDN for samples: [basic_string Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zz6weyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`LPCTSTR` is Microsoft specific type and stands for **L**ong **P**ointer to **C**onstant **T** (Unicode) **STR**ing. In other words, it is `const TCHAR*` where `TCHAR` is generic character (defined in `WinNT.h`):

```
#ifdef UNICODE
   typedef WCHAR TCHAR
#else
   typedef char TCHAR
#endif
```

where `WCHAR` is:

```
typedef wchar_t WCHAR
```

So, `LPCTSTR` is pointer and you cannot do much with string it represents unless you want to play with pointers, count bytes and search for zero-termination character. It is better to use some of string abstractions (classes), like MFC or ATL `CString`, or STL string - `std::string` which is better as you don't depend on MFC/ATL but just standard C++ library. One catch is that STL has string based on narrow- and wide- characters: `std::string` and `std::wstring`. As your code is written for `UNICODE`, you can do something like this:

```
#include <string>

#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef std::wstring tstring;           
#else
    typedef std::string tstring;
#endif

int main()
{
    // ANSI "te-st" or L"te-st" if UNICODE
    TCHAR pszStr[] = TEXT("te-st");

    // const char* or const wchar_t* if UNICODE
    LPCTSTR pStr = pszStr;

    tstring str(pStr);

    tstring sub1 =  str.substr(str.find(TEXT("-")) + 1);
    tstring sub2 =  str.substr(0, str.length() - sub1.length() - 1);        

    // sub1 contains "st" (L"st" if UNICODE) and sub2 contains "te" (L"te" if UNICODE)

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must copy the string, you can't have a pointer to existing buffer, with null terminator where you need it, without changing the buffer, which you can't because it's const (the C in  LPCTSTR).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MFC, you could also construct a CString and use that to get the second half.

```
LPCTSTR both = "first-second";
CString bothStr(both);
CString second_half = bothStr.Right(bothStr.GetLength() -
   (bothStr.Find("-") + 1));
```

Comment: Also note that, typically, if you're using the T string pointer type (note the T in LPCTSTR) you'll also want to surround your string literals with _T() to allow building in Unicode.  The way you have it will work if you're not building Unicode since LPCTSTR will just become LPCSTR and use char * not wchar *.